# return data.table from function in .J in data.table, how?

Tags: r, data.table

```
dt = data.table( v = rnorm(40) , g = rep(c("a","b"),20) )
> head(dt)
```

> ```
>             v g
> 1:  0.5331207 a
> 2: -1.1228596 b
> 3: -0.5366661 a
> 4: -0.3221877 b
> 5:  0.1945076 a
> 6: -0.6483930 b
> ```

I want to do kernel density estimation for each group and store the result in a new `data.table`. So the function performed on each group of the `data.table` will return itself a `matrix` or `data.table`

**Failed attempts:**

```
dt[, .( { tmp = density(x=v) ; list(x=tmp$x,y=tmp$x) } ) , by = .(g) ]

dt[, .( { tmp = density(x=v) ; data.table(x=tmp$x,y=tmp$x) } ) , by = .(g) ]
```

**Desired result:**

> ```
> > x y g
> > -0.5 0.003 a
> > -0.45 0.0413 a
> ...
> > 0.8 0.0013 a
> ...
> > -0.5 0.0026 b
> > -0.45 0.0034 b
> ...
> ```

Comment: If you remove the `.()` from the first code line, you have your desired output. In data.table `.` is just an alias for `list`, so in that code you are really doing `list(list(tmp$x, tmp$y))`, i.e. creating one column containing a list, while your desired output is that of `list(tmp$x, tmp$y)`, i.e. creating two columns each containing numerics.

Comment: A shorter way: `dt[, density(x=v)[c("x","y")], by=g]`

Comment: use `set.seed` when giving example with `rnorm`